# Why are the funds in a transaction not transferred to the account automatically?

Tags: php, paypal

I have setup a Paypal payment environment, for the purpose of selling a certain service. I used Laravel to setup the API endpoints in the server for the creation and the approval of the order.

Whereas in the frontend, I used the paypal buttons, specifying the aforementioned API URL endpoints for the purpose of creating and capturing orders (onCreate and onApprove parameters of the button).

Everything is working as intended, the order is correctly created and verified before the payment is processed, but there's a small problem. For every new order, I have to go to the transaction log of my business account and manually click "Get your money" in order to actually transfer the funds to the account. (Refer to image with a couple of test payments).

With the increasing number of orders, this becomes a very tedious process. I don't quite understand why it is even implemented this way.
Is there a way to automatically transfer the funds to the account when a new order is made?

Have I made a mistake (or missed something) in the implementation of the payment gateway, or is there a default setting in the business account that I have to change?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you require any additional information.
Thank you in advance[image: Visual representation of the problem]

Answer (score 1):

Why is the payment pending? The screenshot does not show the details.

- Is it a currency issue? If you don't have a balance of EUR on the account, open one if you want to receive payments as EUR, or change your payment receiving preferences to automatically convert to your primary currency balance.
- Is the payment an authorization? If so the integration facilitating the creation of these transactions needs to be changed to create transactions that are of type "sale" or immediate capture, rather than authorizations for later capture.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response. I can confirm there is no currency issue. And the payment is not an authorization as the API calls are made with "CAPTURE" intent. The only information I have at the pending transaction is that under "Paid by", paypal informs me the buyer is not verified and not located in the US (for card payments).

Comment: Upon further research, I think this is an actual paypal feature (buyer's protection). It takes a while for paypal to process the payment, because they give the buyer some time to cancel the order (i.e. ask for a refund). Is this an intended design feature? Or am I not understanding it correctly?